# How do i tweak my wp Post title base on category of the post

Tags: functions, categories, wp-title

Hello please i need a wordpress  function.php code where i can choose how to display my title differently in  section wp_title.

E.g.

If home, tag page, Category page, And Pages are viewed then "Normal Title".

But.
And then post titles will have a conditional statement like.

If a post is under "Music" catgegory then the title will have a prefix "Download Music:" before the post title.

E.g Download Music: %post_title%

If a post under "Video" category then the title will have another prefix "Download Video:" before the post title.

E.g Download Video: %post_title%

Etc...

I hope i'm understood??.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a filter in the title like:

```
add_filter('the_title', function ($title) {

if (is_single()) {
    $categories = get_the_category(get_the_ID());
    // Assuming the post has many categories will take the first
    $category = reset($categories);
    return $category->name .' - '.$title;
}
return $title;
});
```

Comment: Please, This code doesnt work, but instead it adds The Prefix on Single page, and Nav bar menu not in <title> title.

Answer (score 0):

Document title renders in _wp_render_title_tag. If you want to modify it, you need to remove the WP function and create your own with similar logic.

Something similar to this:

```
remove_action('wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag', 1);
```

And then:

```
add_filter('wp_head', function () {
    if (!current_theme_supports('title-tag')) {
        return;
    }

    if (did_action('wp_head') || doing_action('wp_head') && is_single()) {
        $categories = get_the_category();
        // Assuming the post has many categories will take the first
        $category = reset($categories);

        if ($category) {
            echo '<title>' . $category->name . ' - ' . get_the_title() . '</title>' . "\n";
        }
    }
    echo '<title>' . wp_get_document_title() . '</title>' . "\n";
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works!!